# MongoDBCompass not opening on Windows Server 2019

Tags: mongodb, windows, windows-server-2019, mongodb-compass

I have installed MongoDB on one windows server 2019 and am able to access it using shell commands but when I try to launch MongoDB Compass software, it doesn't even launch. It shows up in the task manager but UI never comes up

Windows Server is 64 bit

OS - Windows Server 2019 Standard

MongoDB version - 5.0.5 (Community Edition)

Install msi file used - mongodb-windows-x86_64-5.0.5-signed.msi

Answer (score 1):

same problem here

I had no issues before but right now I have two different windows server 2019 servers and both has the same problem

I think it's due to windows update

UPDATE

I switched to Robo 3T and it works just fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).